# Javascript Timer and Casting

Tags: javascript, html, timer

I am developing a Flask app and not very familiar with JS so I am hacking a timer together. I am trying to pull a numeric value from an HTML textfield and use that to determine how many minutes are on the countdown timer.

It works when I replace `Number(document.getElementById(minutes))` with an integer like 5, but not when I try to pull in a value from the textfield. The initial text will display by the time doesn't count down. What is going wrong?

```
function count_time() {
    var in_time = 60 * Number(document.getElementById(minutes)),
        display = document.querySelector('#time');
    startTimer(in_time, display);
};
</script>

<form>
  Minutes:<br>
  <input type="text" name="minutes"><br>
</form>

<button onclick="count_time()">Go</button>

<div>Registration closes in <span id="time">05:00</span> minutes!

</div>
```

Comment: you use `getElementById` but you supply a *variable* called `minutes` as opposed to the string **"minutes"**. In addition, you don't even have an element with the ID **"minutes"**

Comment: `(document.getElementById(minutes))` should be `(document.getElementById('minutes'').value)`

Comment: Also `<input type="text" name="minutes">` should be `<input type="text" name="minutes" id="minutes">`

Comment: Sounds like you need to become more familiar with JS, you've made some really basic mistakes (some of which would be mistakes in other languages, too). You can't expect to be a functional web developer if you have to come here for help every day.

Comment: Luis's solution worked! @Barmar this is the first day I've come here for help in six months if not longer and I think the first day ever for a web dev problem. I'm a CS student who is actually doing really well with back end and will work more on front end when I have time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're accessing a DOM. You'll need to add quotes when getting the id. Unless you have a string variable holding the DOM name which isn't recommended.

```
Number(document.getElementById('minutes').value)
```

You can use `getElementBy` instead of `querySelector` without using them separately. I would use consistency when possible. I would also change `name` to `id`.

Be sure to specify what attribute you want to access after getting the id since you're missing a `.value` when you're getting the minutes.

Speaking of consistency. I would use the same naming convention through your JS script. Like don't have mix variable_name variableName casing. Only time you use different naming options are:

```
VariableName // Pascal case for loading classes.
VARIABLE_NAME // Snake case for constants.
variableName // Camel case for variables and functions.
```

I don't know if this will help since I can't fully see the rest of your code when you call `startTimer`.

Just for extra. I would style the div like this for readability:

```
<div>
  Registration closes in <span id="time">05:00</span> minutes!
</div>
```